# Using Comparison Test for ∑(1/(n^2-ln(n)))

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Good evening all!
I have been stuck on this problem for way too long, and figured I could use a *little* push in the right direction.

I have this series:

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^2 - ln(n)} $$

and would like to use the Comparison Test to prove its convergence. I tried comparing to

$$\sum \frac{1}{n^2 - ln(n)} < \sum \frac{1}{n^2 - n} > \sum \frac{1}{n^2}$$

but this leads me no where, as does just comparing with:

$$ \sum \frac{1}{n^2 - ln(n)} < \sum \frac{1}{n}$$

I then tried using partial fractions:

$$ \sum \frac{1}{n^2 - ln(n)} < \sum \frac{1}{n^2 - n} =  \sum \frac{1}{n-1} - \frac{1}{n}$$

Which, again, leads me no where.

Any *litle* nudge would be very much appreciated!

Comment: $$\sum_{n\geqslant2}\frac{1}{n^2-n}=\sum_{n\geqslant2}\left(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right)=\left(1-\frac12\right)+\left(\frac12-\frac13\right)+\left(\frac13-{}{}{}\frac14\right)+\cdots=1$$

Comment: After a short while, $\ln n\lt \frac{n^2}{2}$, so our expression is after a while less than $\frac{1}{n^2-\frac{n^2}{2}}$, which is $\frac{2}{n^2}$.

Comment: From Wolfram, I get that my series converges to 1.70266. So with that series being equal to 1, aren't I saying that 1.70266 < 1??

Comment: You would saying that if you were summing the same series, but you are summing $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^2-\log n}$ while $1=\sum\limits_{n\geqslant2}\frac1{n^2-n}$. Thus $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^2-\log n}=1+\sum\limits_{n\geqslant2}\frac1{n^2-\log n}<1+\sum\limits_{n\geqslant2}\frac1{n^2-n}$, that is,  $\sum\limits_{n\geqslant1}\frac1{n^2-\log n}<1+1=2$, and it happens that $1.70266<2$. (Unrelated: Next time you address something I wrote in a comment, please use @.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{{1\over {n^2}}\over {1\over {n^2-ln(n)}}}$ = $lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}{{n^2-ln(n)}\over n^2}=lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty} 1-{{ln(n)}\over n^2}=1$.